# failed to resolved support-vector-Drawable

Tags: android, gradle, android-support-library

I have project which was working fine till yesterday but this morning when i try to build it keeps throwing failed to resolved support-vector-Drawable error.
I try to clean and this error shows up

> Error:Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
>   Could not find support-vector-drawable.aar (com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:26.0.2).
>     Searched in the following locations:
>         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-vector-drawable/26.0.2/support-vector-drawable-26.0.2.aar

and here is my gradle

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.arizeh.arizehplus"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 22
    multiDexEnabled true
    versionCode 29
    versionName "3.0.5"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    defaultConfig {
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

dependencies {

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26+'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
}
```

and here is my level build.gradle file

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.24.4'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files

}
```

}

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'http://jhoobin.abroid.com/repo/' }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }

}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: have you added google() to maven repository list?

Comment: @adityakamble49 yes i have!!!

Comment: can you share project level build.gradle file?

Comment: @adityakamble49 sure

Comment: @adityakamble49 I added to the end

Comment: Yeah. It looks ok to me. Maybe some other reason. Try deleting ".gradle" and ".idea" folder from project directory

Comment: @adityakamble49 still no ...

Comment: try invalidate caches and restart

Comment: @prashant17 nothing changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi as per my understanding please try bellow tow thing one

**One is replacing your app compact version dependancy with specific version else of plus**

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26+'
```

Replace with (Please set as per your build tool)

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
```

**And Another thing try updating your build tool version.**

Answer (score 1):

so after half day searching and rebuild finally it fixed by upgrading my compileSdkVersion and all other library to 27 ... I hope this help any one who has this problem

Answer (score 0):

```
defaultConfig {

    defaultConfig {
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
}
```

Change to

```
defaultConfig {
  vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}
```